# Mail to redut.net in Gmail sent mail folder

Tags: gmail, security

I have noticed multiple outgoing mail messages to an address at redut.net in my Gmail "Sent Mail" folder, all sent at around the same time. The contents are base64-encoded and upon decoding it I see my e-mail address at the end. (The rest I find unintelligible, but forgive me if I do not post it.)

I have considered the possibility that these are automatically generated when I use the "unsubscribe and report spam" feature. However, there are **other** messages in my "Sent Mail" folder that look more like what I would expect in that case. Those messages are sent to an address at retrevo.com, where the recipient address appears to contain encoded data, and the message contents say "This message was automatically generated by Gmail."

So, what is `redut.net`, how were these messages sent to them, and what does that mean for me? Did Gmail recently change their unsubscribe feature? Is this a client-tracking mechanism? Or something more sinister?

Comment: Have you checked your filters for any forwarding rules that you didn't create?

Comment: Good question.  There are none other than the one I created myself.

Comment: I'd start with [signing out all the sessions](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2008/07/remote-sign-out-and-info-to-help-you.html) and resetting the password. Also check if you have any external services authorized to access to your Google Account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it has something to do with the “Unsubscribe” function provided by Gmail. At least that’s what the Google Groups forums are saying. (See [here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/k3jNtsn_5-Q) for instance.)

However, just in case, you should change your password and check the apps that have access to your Google Account. To do this, follow the steps below:

1. Sign in on the [Google Accounts homepage](https://www.google.com/accounts).
2. Click **Security**.
3. Click **Edit** next to **Authorizing applications and sites**. This page will list all third-party sites you've granted access to.
4. Click the **Revoke Access** link to disable access for a site.

[Source](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=41236).

Comment: Good answer! I spotted one possible typo - should 'at list' to 'at least'? I'm not able to edit that because edits have to be longer than 6 characters. But would you be able to edit that as the answer owner?

Comment: @culix Thanks for spotting the typo!